# Java : Couldn't find or load main class при использовании Package

Tags: java, ubuntu, package, main

Стоит убунту 16.04 lt, установлен openjdk 1.8.0_131. Программа компилируется. При запуске выдает could not find or load main class. Если удалить package, то программа запускается.В чем проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package out.test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println ("WHY??");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Из документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#sthref48):

> By default, the first argument that is not an option of the java
>   command is the fully qualified name of the class to be called.

По-русски говоря, ожидается полное имя класса, включая пакет:

```
java -cp . out.test.Test
```

Comment: Уже часа 4 ищу ответ, можете по-подробней пожалуйста. Из какой папки надо запускать команду   java  -cp . out.test.Test

Comment: В вашем случае из `/home/lidar/Desktop/Test`. Или из корня, но тогда в параметр `-cp` вместо точки передать `/home/lidar/Desktop/Test`. Про `classpath` можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень выручили